# When clicking URL in E-Mail, the client switches to the browser window

Tags: unity, google-chrome, thunderbird

I want to switch to opened browser window or start new browser window in the current Desktop/Viewport.

When I click a link in Thunderbird, that will open a new Tab in existing browser session/window (and blinking in applet bar).

I want that my browser (Google Chrome) open a new session/window (in current Desktop with TB) or switch automatically to the Desktop with existing opened Chrome window.

May be this funktionality is interesting, then clicking an URL in another application (PDF-Viewer,..).

Can I determine desired functionality systemwide?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: I have found followed solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found followed solution. First, edit file in ~/.local/share/applications/google_chrome_my.desktop. Must contain:

`[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Google Chrome
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --new-window %U
Terminal=false
Icon=google-chrome
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;image/webp;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;`.

Add this .desktop file to your Applet Launcher Bar (Drag and Drop).

Next, add following to file ~/config/mimeapps.list in pragraph [Default Applications](but not in ~/.local/share/applications/):

`text/html=google_chrome_my.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=google_chrome_my.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google_chrome_my.desktop
text/xml=google_chrome_my.desktop
application/xhtml_xml=google_chrome_my.desktop
image/webp=google_chrome_my.desktop
x-scheme-handler/ftp=google_chrome_my.desktop`.

Next logout/login. From now on that must to work.

`xdg-settings set default-web-browser` has no funktion on my Desktop(?).

(thanks to Post in linux.org.ru: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/desktop/12427558?lastmod=1457875649636#comment-12427623
and
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/MIME-Typ/#Standardanwendung-festlegen)